# Send Email through External Email Services by using Apex and Lightning Component

Tags: email, apex-email-service

I built a lightning component with an email sending feature. It is working correctly through Salesforce internal Email service. But I have a requirement to **send email through my Gmail account** just like the salesforce has the inbuilt feature **"My Email Settings"** and **"Send through External Email Services"**. But this feature is not working with the lightning component. I want to implement this below feature through Apex and lightning component.

[image]

Please help me with any suggestions or resources on this.

[image]

Here is my Apex code snippet-

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    List<OrgWideEmailAddress> owaList = [select id, Address from OrgWideEmailAddress where DisplayName = 'Sam Test'];
    if(owaList.size()>0)
    {
        mail1.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owaList.get(0).id);
    }

    mail1.setUseSignature(false);
    mail1.setToAddresses(new String[] { PMEmail });
    mail1.setReplyTo(owaList.get(0).Address); 
    mail1.setSubject(ProjectSubjectPickup);
    mail1.setHtmlBody(EmailBody1);
    mail1.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachMail1 });
    system.debug('<===>mail1' + mail1); 
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail1 });
```

Comment: Check this link : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_maximize_productivity/sales_admin_maximize_productivity_unit_2

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But It is for Salesforce integrated feature that I have mentioned. Emails sent through workflows and triggers are still sent through Salesforce. I want this in apex.

Comment: Hey there Have you checked the user permission "Send email through external Email Services" and/or and have you integrated it completely?

Comment: Currently "Send email through external Email Services" feature is working fine in my sandbox. What type of permission you are referring to?

Comment: There is a permission on profile that allows a user to send through external services but I believe it is checked by default so it should be fine. Maybe if you posted your lightning component code we could help you better

Comment: Hi, @KDH I posted my apex code snippet. The lightning component code is a very basic form with a "Send Mail" button. Can you please let me know if it is possible from apex to send mail through Gmail.

Comment: Hey @Sam, Sorry for the late reply. I thought it may be an issue with running apex in system mode and not using a user's email settings but after some testing, it just seems like emails can't be sent through Gmail from apex although not stated anywhere they only say not from triggers and workflows which is annoying. It could be an option for you to set up a relay through Gmail though but thats a lot  more work