# Gmail Api integartion with Salesforce using Rest Api

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I want to send email from gmail.
Implementation will be like this.

In lightning component we will have a button named "Send", once someone click on it will trigger an email.

Is it possible? I have checked Trigger and workflow is not supported.
also in API documentation I can see they do not support all programming languages and need library as well.

Can anyone please help on this?
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Pinaki

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Right now, it is not clear what you've tried or where you're stuck. Salesforce has built-in functionality to send email. Triggers and workflows are always written in Apex and have nothing to do with external libraries, but you can make API calls. Please take a look at [ask] and [edit] your post to be specific about the problem and show us where you are stuck.

Comment: I was stuck in the same problem before. Sending email from salesforce through Gmail is supported from the Salesforce Admin part. Till now I didn't find any solution on this one from apex. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286927/send-email-through-external-email-services-by-using-apex-and-lightning-component --Also lastly I am not understanding why this question was closed. Thanks.